# Rails: How to loop through parameters of post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

Given these paramters:

```
{
    "items"=>{"id"=>"", "id"=>"", "id"=>""}
}
```

How would I go about assigning the content for each item in rails?

This is what I have tried:

```
    params[:items].each do |i|
        item = Item.find(i)
            @content = params[:s]
        end
    end
```

It obviously cannot find any value for `params[:s]`, so `@content` is equals `nil`.

I have absolutely no idea on how to get this value. I appreciate each answer. Thank you!

Comment: This question seems unclear to me. What exactly do you want to do?!

Comment: How do your parameters look like exactly? If you use 3 times the same key in a Hash, the last one will overwrite the others : `{"id"=>"a", "id"=>"b", "id"=>"c"}` is just `{"id"=>"c"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the `Hash` class, specifically the [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) method. There are *two* parameters in the block, a key and a value. So adding that second parameter will allow you to get that value:

```
params[:items].each do |id, value|
  # You can access the value for each ID 
  # with the variable 'value' while in the block
end
```

I'm not sure why you're setting `@content` repeatedly. That's the same variable throughout the whole script; are you trying to set a `content` attribute on each `item`? If so, you just need to say `item.content = value` (and probably save `item` at some point, if you want it to persist in the database). And you wouldn't need to put that within a block for `Item.find`; just put it on the next line(s) within the outer block. (If you did need a block for `Item.find`, you appear to be missing a `do` on that line.)